# iOS - How to start a new line in UITextView while streaming from remote service

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nstimer

In my ios application, I am streaming text from a remote service to a UITextView.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var streamingResult: UITextView!

 // Store streaming results in a String called results
 var results : String = ""
```

I don't know when text is coming in or not. But whenever there is a pause, I want to start a new line on the UILabel.

So I have resorted to using a NSTimer to detect when there is no text for 3 seconds like this:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, 
selector: "pauseExists", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

My selector is hit as expected when there is no text coming in, and I tried to add a new line character like this:

```
@objc func pauseExists() {
    print("No stream for 3 seconds")

    guard let currentText = self.streamingResult.text else { return }
    if !currentText.isEmpty {
       self.results.append("\n")
       self.streamingResult.text = self.results
    } 
}
```

This doesn't work, the next result gets added right after the previous one. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What's the label's `numberOfLines`? Also, `UITextView` is probably better suited for multi-line text, and storing data in UI objects only is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Gereon I have never explicitly set the `numberOfLines` on `UILabel`. I am not really storing text, not sure if storing is the right word because I am just displaying the result of the stream on it. Would `UITextView ` be better?

Comment: @Gereon setting the number of lines to 0 on `UILabel` did not work by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better example for you. Use UITextView instead. It is better and comes with a free UIScroll.

```
let label : UITextView = {
        let label = UITextView()
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        label.isEditable = false
        return label
}()

lazy var appendButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Append", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    return button
}()

var foo : String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(appendButton)
    appendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    appendButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    appendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    appendButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    appendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    appendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appendButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)


    self.view.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.pauseExists), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func pauseExists() {
    print("No stream for 1 second")
    foo.append("\n")
    label.text = foo
}

@objc func appendButtonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
    foo.append("New Line")
    label.text = foo
}
```

Run this code in an empty project and you will see how new lines get appended every time you press the Append button. Hope it helps

Comment: please see updated Post with your answer, it still does not go to new line

Comment: Also `var newText = currentText + "\n" + "new text"` isn't very efficient because you keep copying the entire streaming result over and over again?

Comment: Well, yes. It is not a good practice. Just wanted to follow the way you are doing it. If you want something more efficient you should store the String in a variable instead of using what you already have in the label. Storing data in UI components is never a good idea. Please see my answer for something much better.

Comment: This makes sense, but this would result in every word coming in being added to a new line like this: `hello` new line `hello this` new line `hello this is` new line `hello this is a` new line `hello this is a test`

Comment: That is why I wanted to use a NSTimer and put the append new line action only in the selector

Comment: Maybe I have to append result of the stream to the `UITextView` in the selector as well, I don't know of any other options

Comment: Why exactly will that happen? At any point you can have the string updated to append a new string and then append \n for the new line. See update in my answer. I am using the exact same function as you are.

Comment: This makes sense. I figured out the problem is actually the stream coming in is overwriting the new line and just appending to the last line. That is a separate problem though.